# How do namespace work in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to instantiate a class that use namespace.

```
<?php
namespace CFPropertyList;   

require_once('CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php');

$plist = new CFPropertyList();
?>
```

That's working!

But when I try put that code into my class I get syntax errors. I can't use "namespace CFPropertyList;" in a class?

```
 <?php
class Plist{
    public function test(){
       namespace CFPropertyList;    

       require_once('CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php');

       $plist = new CFPropertyList();
   }

}
?>
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to all I got this working.

```
<?php
namespace CFPropertyList;
require_once('CFPropertyList/CFPropertyList.php');

 class Plist{
    public function test(){
      //some code
    }
 }

}
```

But is my own class in a namespace now? Sorry for the noob questions.
I can't do.

```
   $plist = new Plist;
   $plist->test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your namespace should be declared before your class, so the class would then belong to that namespace:

plist.php

```
 <?php
  namespace CFPropertyList; 

  class Plist{
      public function test() {
          echo 'Test';
      }
  }
?>
```

other.php

```
 <?php
  require_once('plist.php');

  $plist = new CFPropertyList::Plist();
  $plist.test();
?>
```

Comment: That's working but, now I got a new problem '$plist = new Plist; $plist->test();'.   Class 'Plist' not found

Comment: If you are calling it from outside the namespace you need CFPropertyList::Plist

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the namespace definition outside the class definition.
(Besides that your class definition seems to be pretty messed up. Don't you have any class methods?)

Comment: fixed the methods! =) but I can't put the namespace outside the class definition.

Comment: That's the only way. See the answer by @air4x.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Defining namespaces`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)

> Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. A file containing
>   a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before
>   any other code - with one exception: the declare keyword.

So you must declare it at the top of the file.